# Using node.js and socket.io alongside Zend Framework application

Tags: node.js, zend-framework, socket.io

I've built a Zend Framework application. I want to implement node.js and socket.io in this application,
but I have no clue where to start.

 I've only used node and socket.io to make a [simple chat application](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/).
If anyone could give me some pointers as for where to start or what steps to take to get a better understanding of how this implementation should work.

Thanks!


I've seen
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14704545/how-to-use-node-js-and-socket-io-in-zend-framework)
 question, but it's really outdated.

Comment: make a separate node application. Send request to the zend application through an api. Your front can init multiple connections with multiple services, it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @unex Do you have an example of  an api that i could use to do this?

Comment: No you have to make your own api in the zend app, and use it from your node app.