# How to use Node.js in ZendFramework 2 to create React Applications

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, zend-framework2

I have a Zend Framework Project, I want to use Node Js to make reusable components, in other words, I want to create some **React pages** in my existing **Zend Framework 2** application. But, I've no idea how to do so, I have made a react app using npm but it runs on localhost,but I want to use node js in my existing Zend project. Please help.
I've seen [How to use node.js and socket.io in zend framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14704545/how-to-use-node-js-and-socket-io-in-zend-framework) and [Using node.js and socket.io alongside Zend Framework application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47674505/using-node-js-and-socket-io-alongside-zend-framework-application) but I am unable to understand the right way to do so. 
Also, is there any other best alternative to create a react app and integrate it with existing zend application.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Node is needed to build client-side React app. It isn't necessary to run it. It's used to not require external web server to serve client-side JS.

Comment: @estus can you please ellaborate? I need to build a React app inside my existing Zendframework 2 app. Is it possible to do so? If yes, then how. I'm new to node and I'm confused and don't know how to start.

Comment: Node is used by webpack to create JavaScript (and optionally other resources like CSS). If you plan to use webpack dev server that need to consume PHP end points you can use webpack dev server to serve the html/js/css and proxy ajax requests to your php server. The end result of your "react app" is just some files served statically by your web server but during development webpack dev server can come in handy.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the framework. You use Zend to run your application. Node is needed to build React app, not to run it. It's development dependency, not production dependency. *don't know how to start* - install Node and run `npm i && npm run build` inside React project. The result is plain JS files that can be deployed to the server.